# Problems clicking windows

Tags: 14.04, unity, themes, xserver

When I double-click on the header of a window in my Ubuntu installation, it disappears, and I don't know why, I mean, the normal way of working is to maximize or stay in the previous configuration after maximizing, but the window actually disappears.

I had installed a Unity theme which seems to have been the main problem, but I have deleted it now, but the problem still prevails.

So does anyone have any suggestions on how to return its behaviour to normal?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do anything, so I had to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @v2r This is the OP's answer to their question - what they finally ended up doing.

Comment: @muru Now that you mention it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unity tweak tool to configure what happens when the window is double clicked.
Unity tweak tool is available in the software centre, just search it. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: No, I don't have these options in unity tweak tool. It seems like a problem in the way of working....